# USB devices are intermittently disconnecting when connected through a KVM switch

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, kvm-switch

**The problem:**

I have a keyboard and mouse hooked up to my Dell U3419W monitor, which has a built-in KVM switch and is connected to both my desktop and my laptop. Both the desktop and laptop are Windows 10, and are connected to the monitor with a USB cable and an HDMI cable. The monitor works fine with both the laptop and the desktop, but the keyboard and mouse only play nice with my laptop, not my desktop. They seem to intermittently disconnect, but it's not like a complete disconnect where the computer makes a noise like when you unplug something, it's like a soft disconnect where they just stop sending input to the computer and the lights on my keyboard turn off.

At this point I think that this is a software problem and not a hardware problem because I created a bootable Linux USB stick, and ran it on my desktop and the keyboard and mouse both worked fine when it was running Linux and did not disconnect. Plus everything works fine with my laptop, so if it was an issue with the KVM switch or whatever I should notice it on my laptop too I would think

**What I've tried:**

- Swapping out the cables used
- Swapping out which ports on the monitor I have stuff plugged into
- Swapping out which ports on the desktop I have stuff plugged into
- Uninstalling/reinstalling Windows
- Updating my motherboard BIOS/chipset drivers
- Uninstalling my USB devices from Device Manager and then letting Windows reinstall them
- Disabling the USB power saving option in Windows
- Disabling USB selective suspend in power options

The only thing I've seen recommended online that I should try but haven't is installing the USB drivers in compatability mode. I can't figure out where to download the USB drivers for my motherboard (ASUS Prime Z-490M Plus).

Comment: I have pretty much the same issue. The mouse and keyboard seem to disconnect temporarily. Only one machine (my laptop) is affected - desktop is fine. I've also tried changing from wired to wireless mouse/keyboard but the same issue occurs.